# Can't create Kubernetes cluster in Google Cloud from web UI

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I removed a bunch of IAM policies and think this is preventing me from creating k8s clusters in Google Cloud (through the UI).

Every time I click `Create cluster`, it processes for a bit, before hanging up and throwing the following error:

```
Create Kubernetes Engine cluster "standard-cluster-1"
Just now
MyProject
Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.zones.get' permission for 'projects/<MY_PROJECT_ID>/zones/us-central1-a'.
```

I'm mainly doing this through my host shell (iTerm) and **NOT** through the interactive shell found on cloud.google.com.

Here's the IAM policy for a user (I use my google email address under the `Member` column):

[image: clou]

Really hoping to get unblocked so I can start creating clusters in my shell again and not have to use the interactive shell on the Google Cloud website.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. `Compute Admin` has `compute.zones.get` permission. Do you see the right account when you run `gcloud auth list`?

Comment: @suren definitely know I'm doing something wrong. I do see the account there (and it's selected).

Comment: does it work from the cloud shell?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Denis It's been awhile, but I actually ended up completely killing the service account (and all others) and creating a new one from scratch.

Comment: @bob_cobb thank you for the hint. It was sufficient for me to disable and enable back Kubernetes Engine API. And google cloud automatically recovered required roles for some service accounts, which roles were accidentally removed.

Comment: @Denis Glad it worked. I suspect it's some weird edge case and not well documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing ServiceAgent roles. But only service accounts can be granted those roles.

1) First,  copy you [project number](https://console.cloud.google.com/?_ga=2.90704154.-1064291117.1550565601)

2) create following members for the Service Agents replacing *77597574896* with your project number and set appropriate roles:

```
service-77597574896@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com  - Kubernetes Engine Service Agent
service-77597574896@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com - Kubernetes Engine Service Agent
77597574896@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com - Editor
```

[image]

This should work now, because I've tested it with my cluster

Answer (score 0):

In order to create new cluster container - please just add new role in yours IAM settings:
`- Kubernetes Engine Admin,`
Please share with the results.